# AnyLogic Loop as Action on Exit

Tags: java, loops, anylogic

I'm trying to build a little delivery model in AnyLogic.
I recive orders in my factory and want to transfer them to the trucks.
The idea is, to send the orders to the truck, until the capacity is reached (in this testing model  only 2) and then choose the next truck with space.
At the exit block of the factory I have following code as "Action on Exit".
The "agent" is the order.

```
for (int i=0; i==2; i++)
 {
 if (main.trucks.get(i).queue.size() < 2)
 {main.trucks.get(i).enter.take(agent);
 break;
 }
 }
```

The orders never reached the trucks, why?
With real numbers it is working, it has to do something with the loop.
Or is it not possible to use loops in the Actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should really be achieved using a **Pickup** block in the Process Modelling library with `Exact quantity (wait for)` option for pickup mode. For more info, please consult [help for **Pickup**](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/processmodeling/pickup.html)